# .Net Core 3.1 - HTTP request - Send header and body separately

Tags: c#, .net-core, httprequest

I'm using legacy server, which requires that header and body in HTTP POST requests are sent separately. I suppose this is achieved with 'Expect: 100-continue', which is present in legacy's client message header.

I'm writing new client with use of Net Core 3.1, which seems doesn't have support of Expect100Continue in HttpWebRequest class (According to: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/25881)

Is there any possibility, to send HTTP request with Net Core 3.1 with separated body and header?

Comment: Server is defaulting to http 1.1 while net is not sending the 100 continue.  The solution is for Net client  to send header to server command to change from default http 1.1 to http 1.0.  Use following code :             HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("URI");
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

Comment: HttpWebRequest is deprecated, use HttpClient instead, either for HTTP/1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick solution was turning off net core's HTTP handler with

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
```

After this switch, handler from .net framework is used. It looks like that SocketsHttpHandler (at least with combination with HttpWebRequest) doesn't support separated headers and bodies, even when HTTP 1.0 is used.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appcontext.setswitch?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: It's always nice figuring it out on your own. Thanks for the update.